# service apache2 start => /etc/init.d/apache2: 64: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars

Tags: apache2, services

I have downloaded apache2 source and configured and installed manually. But when I try to start the service, this error shows up.

```
$ service apache2 start

/etc/init.d/apache2: 64: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
/etc/init.d/apache2: 76: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it can happen due to permission issue , try giving

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

Comment: i had tried that too